# How can i share video from application?

Tags: android, android-studio, video, share

I want to share video from app, but i don't know how to do it. How share video without download?

i tried donwload video and than share, But i don't need download that video.

```
                String type = "Video/*";
                String fileName = mNum;
                String MediaPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/folder/" + str;
                MediaPath = MediaPath.replace("/storage/emulated/0/folder/","storage/emulated/0/Android/data/relax.justrelax/files/folder/");

                Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                share.setType(type);
                File file = new File(MediaPath);
                Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
                share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "share"));
```

I can share with download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How share video without download?

Use `EXTRA_TEXT` and put the URL in as part of your message.

Comment: i don't need that, because my videos save in dropBox

Comment: @andrey: Then you need to download the video. Either share a public URL as text or share a local video as a `content` `Uri` via `EXTRA_STREAM`. Those are your only two options.

Comment: okey, i use Donwload manager. and i don't want to show that my app donwload video on phone. How can i hide progress?

long downloadReference;

        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager)context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
        request.setTitle("sha");
        request.setDescription("");
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context,
                    "/folder", "/" + name);
        downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
        return downloadReference;

Comment: @andrey: "How can i hide progress?" -- [use `setDownloadVisibility()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setNotificationVisibility(int)). Or, use an in-app HTTP client (e.g., OkHttp) to download the video.